# How would I create a trail behind my shapes in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Right now I have some shapes (I only included the triangle as they're all generated the same way) that are generated when the user spins the mouse wheel. I want to leave a trail behind the shapes that slowly disappear. I've looked around and tried a few different ways but I can't seem to get any of them to work. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var canvas;
    var context;
    var triangles = [];
    var timer;

    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        resizeCanvas();
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', resizeCanvas, false);
        canvas.onwheel = function(event) {
            handleClick(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        };
        var timer = setInterval(resizeCanvas, 30);
    }

    function Triangle(x,y,triangleColor) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.triangleColor = triangleColor;

            this.vx = Math.random() * 30 - 15;
            this.vy = Math.random() * 30 - 15;
            this.time = 100;
    }

function handleClick(x,y) {
        var colors = [[0,170,255], [230,180,125], [50,205,130]];
        var triangleColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
        triangles.push(new Triangle(x,y,triangleColor));
        for (var i=0; i<triangles.length; i++) {
            drawTriangle(triangles[i]);
        }
}

function drawTriangle(triangle) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(triangle.x,triangle.y); 
            context.lineTo(triangle.x+25,triangle.y+25);
            context.lineTo(triangle.x+25,triangle.y-25);
            var c = triangle.triangleColor
            context.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + c[0] + ', ' + c[1] + ', ' + c[2] + ', ' + (triangle.time / 100) + ')';
            context.fill();
}

function resizeCanvas() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth-20;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight-20;
        fillBackgroundColor();
        for (var i=0; i<triangles.length; i++) {
            var t = triangles[i];
            drawTriangle(t);

            if (t.x + t.vx > canvas.width || t.x + t.vx < 0)
                t.vx = -t.vx
            if (t.y + t.vy > canvas.height || t.y + t.vy < 0)
                t.vy = -t.vy
            if (t.time === 0) {
                triangles.splice(i,1);
            }

            t.time -= 1;
            t.x += t.vx;
            t.y += t.vy;
        }
}

function fillBackgroundColor() {
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}

    window.onload = init;
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I managed to do this is by storing past locations of my objects (for example 10 past locations, and draw line from one to the next one.

1.Add arrays pastX and pastY to your triangle object.

```
this.pastX = [];
this.pastY = [];
```

2.Each tick put every element 1 place further and add current location as first.

**Right before you update triangle positions**

```
    for(var k = t.pastX.length; k > 0; k--){
        if(k < 10){
        t.pastX[k] = pastX[k-1];
        t.pastY[k] = pastY[k-1];
        }
     t.pastX[0] = t.x;
     t.pastY[0] = t.y;
```

3. draw lines between them like this (from 0 to 1, from 1 to 2 and so on);

   for(var k = 0; k < t.pastX.length - 1; k++){
   //draw line from pastX[k], pastY[k] to pastX[k + 1], pastY[k + 1]
   }

Hope I helped you.